# How to use multiple Composite Aggregations in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am trying to obtain two [composite aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html) in ElasticSearch but the second one is always giving me an empty bucket.

`GET /resolutions/_search`

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "*"
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "total": {
            "composite": {
                "sources": [
                    {"doi": {"terms": {"field": "doi"}}},
                    {"access_method": {"terms": {"field": "access_method"}}}
                ],
                "size": 10000
            }
        },
        "unqiue": {
            "composite": {
                "sources": [
                    {"doi": {"terms": {"field": "doi"}}},
                    {"access_method": {"terms": {"field": "access_method"}}},
                    {"session": {"terms": {"field": "session"}}}
                ],
                "size": 10000
            }
        }
    },
    "size": 0,
    "track_total_hits": false
}
```

In the response, you can see the first aggregation (`total`) with 1000s of objects in the bucket but the second one  aggreagtion (`unique`) is always empty. I have tried swaping the order of the aggregations and it's always the second one in order that is empty.

[![Reponse with second bucket empty][2]][2]

[image]

The index mapping are in: https://github.com/datacite/shiba-inu/blob/2d632d341a22a8dca2afec3b01c3b34030144c9c/templates/aggregating_es.json

Why is it returning an empty bucket?

Comment: hey there :) I have the same problem, it seems to happends when you've got more than 2 sources.. Could you fix it? or confirm my thoughts? Thanks! Max

Answer (score 0):

The `"after_key"` indicates that there are still results left. The search returned the first page. For further pagination you need to repeat the same request with `"after"` set to the value from the `"after_key"`. Repeat this with every new after_key until the after_key is missing.

Example from [elastic](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.14/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html#_pagination)

```
GET /_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "my_buckets": {
      "composite": {
        "size": 2,
        "sources": [
          { "date": { "date_histogram": { "field": "timestamp", "calendar_interval": "1d", "order": "desc" } } },
          { "product": { "terms": { "field": "product", "order": "asc" } } }
        ],
        "after": { "date": 1494288000000, "product": "mad max" } 
      }
    }
  }
}
```